# Quality of XSZ / KSZ sets on AliExpress

Tags: clone-brands, bionicle

There's a LEGO-compatible brand called "Smartable" or KSZ (or XSZ, I can't tell) that appear on AliExpress. Do you know the quality of their parts?

Comment: Welcome to Bricks.SE I've edited your question a little to make it a bit more clear. Hope you don't mind that!

Comment: I've further restructured the question to focus on the brand itself and removed links and references to specific sets that infringe on TLG's trademark or copyright.

Answer (score 7):

From [WP KO Bricks Wiki](https://sites.google.com/site/wpkobrickswiki/home)

[XSZ / KSZ](https://sites.google.com/site/wpkobrickswiki/manufacturers/xsz):

> Brick Quality: Not great. The ball joint sockets of constraction figs (Star Wars and Bionicles) can be tight and prone to cracking if forced too much. Only recommended as display models as these problems make them unsuitable for play.